# Spark: how to read chunk of a table from Cassandra

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark

I have a large table that grows vertically. I want to read rows in small batches, so that I can process each and save results.

Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( 
uid timeuuid, 
events blob, 
PRIMARY KEY ((uid)) 
)
```

#### Code attempt 1 - using CassandraSQLContext

```
// Step 1. Get uuid of the last row in a batch
val max = 10
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("foo", "bar")
var cassandraRows = rdd.take(max)
var lastUUID = cassandraRows.last.getUUID("uid"); 
// lastUUID = 131ea620-2e4e-11e4-a2fc-8d5aad979e84


// Step 2. Use last row as a pointer to the start of the next batch
val cc = new CassandraSQLContext(sc)
val cql = s"SELECT events from foo.bar where token(uid) > token($lastUUID) limit $max"

// which is at runtime
// SELECT events from foo.bar WHERE 
// token(uid) > token(131ea620-2e4e-11e4-a2fc-8d5aad979e84) limit 10

cc.sql(cql).collect()
```

Last line throws

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.79] failure:
>   ``)'' expected but identifier ea620 found
>
> SELECT events from foo.bar where token(uid) >
>   token(131ea620-2e4e-11e4-a2fc-8d5aad979e84) limit 10
>                                                                                 ^
>           at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.AbstractSparkSQLParser.apply(SparkSQLParser.scala:33)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:79)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:79)

But it returns correct 10 records if I run my cql in *cqlsh*.

#### Code attempt 2 - using DataStax Cassandra connector

```
// Step 1. Get uuid of the last row in a batch
val max = 10
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("foo", "bar")
var cassandraRows = rdd.take(max)
var lastUUID = cassandraRows.last.getUUID("uid"); 
// lastUUID = 131ea620-2e4e-11e4-a2fc-8d5aad979e84

// Step 2. Execute query
rdd.where(s"token(uid) > token($lastUUID)").take(max)
```

This throws

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0
>   in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost): java.io.IOException: Exception during
>   preparation of SELECT "uid", "events" FROM "foo"."bar" WHERE
>   token("uid") > ? AND token("uid") <= ? AND uid > $lastUUID ALLOW
>   FILTERING: line 1:118 no viable alternative at character '$'

**How to use `where token(...)` queries in spark and Cassandra?**

Comment: not sure what exactly is causing the error but the spark query should use SQL syntax rather than CQL because you are using `CassandraSQLContext`, possibly u need to wrap the uuid in quotes

Comment: `token` must not be an SQL function consider switching to standard datastax connector rather than the SQL context

Comment: CQL queries are very limited, I would use it solely for loading the necessary data in and then just use as a normal RDD

Comment: do the same query but get rid of the `WHERE` part and do the ranges in spark, the types of queries you are allowed to do depend on how ur clustering columns are arranged in cassandra,

Answer (score 0):

I would use the DataStax Cassandra Java Driver. Similar to your CassandraSQLContext, you would select chunks like this:

```
val query = QueryBuilder.select("events")
  .where(gt(token("uid"),token(lastUUID))
  .limit(10)
val rows = session.execute(query).all()
```

If you want to asynchronously query, `session` also has `executeAsync`, which returns a `RichListenableFuture` which can be wrapped by a scala `Future` by adding a callback.